# htaccess simple Redirect doesn't work with trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, slash, trailing

I find a lot of answers to this question (and I have read dozens of them), but they are all about more advanced stuff with patterns and such stuff.
I just need a very simple and basic redirect for static urls.
If I add a trailing slash to the url, the redirect doesn't work and I just can't figure out why.
Example:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /content https://www.example.com/site/content.html
Redirect 301 /content/ https://www.example.com/site/content.html
```

`https://example.com/content` does work, `https://example.com/content/` redirects to `https://example.com/site/`

What is the problem here?

Comment: Is `content` a real directory? Does it have a .htaccess too?

Comment: No and yes. It is a TYPO3 site, but I've placed the redirects at the top of the htaccess file and there are no matching folder names in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `mid_rewrite` rules with `Redirect` (mod_alias). Use this rule as **very first rule** in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^content/?$ https://www.example.com/site/content.html [L,NC,R=302]
```